# Google Custom search bug?

Tags: google-search-api

I have implemented google custom search (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#request) that searches flickr and other sources on my site and now suddenly it gives me very wierd results.

My query looks like this (key and search engine id removed)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?num=10&rights=cc_attribute&searchType=image&safe=high&key={key}&cx={searchengine}&q=cat&start=1
```

So a search on 'cat' obviously gives totalResult:219000 in the response. I get 10 result per request but when I use start=11

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?num=10&rights=cc_attribute&searchType=image&safe=high&key={key}&cx={searchengine}&q=cat&start=11
```

I get totalResults:12!

What am I doing wrong? This used to work.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Can you post the engine's id (cx)? Quota is counted against your API key so cx can be public.

Comment: cx=008479010990451952588:6n9shnvqzwc

Comment: Im quessing it has to do with my rights restriction (I only want pictures one can freely use). In my actual use of the call i use rights=cc_publicdomain|cc_publicdomain|cc_attribute|cc_sharealike|cc_noncommercial|cc_nonderived